# Fabric local zsh alias

Tags: python, emacs, zsh, fabric

To commit all tracked changes, in my fabfile I have:

```
local("git commit -a")
```

and in my .zshenv I have:

```
alias emacs="emacs -nw"
export EDITOR=emacs
```

However, when I call the fabfile function, it still spawns the GUI version of Emacs (which doesn't seem to work from terminal). What am I missing to have Fabric and hence Git use my Emacs alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many elements in the chain: fabric, shell etc. Alias can be not in effect in these situations.
Why don't you simply issue this command

```
git config core.editor "emacs -nw"
```

Comment: That works, and after running `git commit` on its own and getting the same problem I realise that `EDITOR="emacs -nw"` is possibly the way to fix it at a shell level.